# Callback of RabbitMQ returning nothing

Tags: php, rabbitmq, queue

I am working with RabbitMQ in PHP. I am able to send message but getting problem at receiving end.

Here is my code for Sender

```
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$consumerTag = 'consumer' . getmypid();
$channel->queue_declare('loggingQ', false, true, false, false);

$msg = new AMQPMessage("hi");
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'loggingQ');

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

Here is the code for receiver

```
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare('loggingQ', false, true, false, false);

$callback = function($msg) {
    echo $msg->body;
};
$channel->basic_consume('loggingQ', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);
while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
   $channel->wait();
} 

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

Now the problem is at my receiver end it never echo the message. It is just keep requesting like never ending process.

How do I get my message in **callback** method. It never print anything.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I assume your starting the receiver before you start the Sender.

Comment: @NigelRen  No these both code are placed in different files. Sender files calls the receiver code's file. So in any case first sender file will execute then the receiver.

Comment: Hey @SunilPachlangia Did you managed to solve this issue? If so, how?

Comment: @AliRaza I was doing silly thing, I never started my subscriber and was just pushing msg. We have to have 2 application one as Publisher and one as Subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

I've not a huge amount of experience with RabbitMQ so sorry for probably a bad explanation, but the way I've used it was following the tutorials at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html.  I think normally it is assumed that your workers are ready to process any messages sent (this depends on the queue type).

If you want you message to persist, you need to call it as...

```
$msg = new AMQPMessage("hi",
       array('delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT)
       );
```